# How to make a Javascript objects from given JSON data format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, object

Hi I need help understanding how can I create objects from given JSON data:

```
   {
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[

      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "dbh":6
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -79.96474,
               40.46283
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "dbh":2
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -80.00949,
               40.42532
            ]
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "dbh":12
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -79.93531,
               40.42282
            ]
         }
      }
```

I have done following:

```
let rsuCountsData = await axios.get('https://rsu-manager-apigateway 5xm3e3o5.uc.gateway.dev/rsucounts');
      this.createGeoJson(rsuCountsData.data); //calling the below function
```

I created the following function to get the value of count :

```
createGeoJson(data){
 //geojson={}
 //extract the count from data and store it in a object
 for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  console.log(key, value.count); //key= ip address
```

}

}

Now inside this function I want to create objects from that above JSON data but I am not sure how to do that because it looks too nested for me figure it out.Below is what I have done.It is mix of pseudo code and JS.Also don't think its correct but can someone help me point in correct direction how I can store these values in JS objects inside createGeoJson function:

```
     geojson = {}
      geojson.type = "FeatureCollection"
      geojson.features = []

   for key, val in data:
   feat.type = "Feature"
   props.count = val.count
    props.ipAddress = val.ipAddress// this is the key in above function.
   feat.properties = props
   geojson.features.append(feat)
```

Thanks and appreciate any input

Comment: What is an example of the output you want to achieve?

Comment: {
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "bsm":0,
     "ipaddress":0.0.0.0
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
               -79.91746,
               40.44356
            ]
          
         }
      
      }
   ]
} Is it possible to store these Json objects into JavaScript objects individually?

Comment: @Poala Can you show the json that you want to get ?

Comment: There is no `count` property in the JSON you show, so it is unclear how you are getting the "value of count" using that function.

Comment: I think we're all confused because `rsuCountsData.data` is already a JS object.

Comment: count is dbh in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert JSON string to plain JS object.

After that you can iterate it with [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) or any [other iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, (after parsing your string via `JSON.parse()`) you can loop over your `Object.feature` array with the `.forEach` function ([see MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)).

Not 100% sure what your exact output should be but this looks like a good use case for the `.map()` function ([MDN documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).
Say, you have your JSON stored in `const json`, you could do something like:

```
const json = { ... }
const newArray = json.features.map(el => Object.assign({},{type: el.type, properties: el.properties, geoType: el.geometry.type}));
```

`newArray` will be filled with Objects created from empty Objects and the `Object.assign()` function ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign))

**EDIT**: You can also access the index within the `.map()` function for your counter.

Comment: I guess my question how do I parse complex JSON structure.Like in easy ones its easy but like what mine look like it looks complex as hell to me.

Comment: @Poala `JSON.parse` will parse any valid JSON text, no matter how complex. Once it has done so, everything else is not parsing. It is manipulation, aggregation, projection, any number of other techniques to massage the data into a form you can use.